# How to use any icons with Nuxt or Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm facing an error with Nuxtjs when I try to use the vue-fontawesome framework and also the @nuxtjs/fontawesome framework, this is the error:

```
[nuxt] [request error] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'component')
    at $id_c50a96b3 (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:3239:31)
    at async __instantiateModule__ (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:19193:3)
```

this is my code in `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/fontawesome'
  ],

  fontawesome: {
    icons: {
      solid: ['faXmark']
    }
  }
})
```

And this is the component where I want to use the icon:

```html
<template>
  <div :class="props.className">
    <font-awesome-icon icon="xmark" />
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

By the way, the error just appear when I try to load the page, not when I run it.

Comment: It looks like the error is not coming from what you've shared. Isn't there a `.component` somewhere in your code? The left part looks to be undefined sometimes.

Comment: No, theres no other file that I created that have some line with that, but actually the rest of the error show this:
`at $id_c50a96b3 (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:3239:31)
  at async __instantiateModule__ (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:19193:3)`

Comment: Oh, so you're using Nuxt3. Not sure if this module is compatible with it.

Comment: Since last commit was 15months ago, we can be sadly confident it's not compatible with Nuxt 3. You'll have to find another way to install your fontawesome library with a plugin / module of your own!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend this solution by [antfu](https://twitter.com/antfu7), which is IMO by far the best approach to work with any kind of icons: https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-icons
Check the more [in-depth article](https://antfu.me/posts/icons-in-pure-css) explaining why and how the whole thing works.

---

Here's a quick way on how to use it with Nuxt3, first off the requirements:

- be sure to use Node v16 or later
- start a new Nuxt3 project: `pnpm dlx nuxi init nuxt3-unplugin-icons`
- I'm using PNPM, so `pnpm i --shamefully-hoist`
- add the aforementioned package with `pnpm add -D unplugin-icons`

Get this in your `nuxt.config.ts` file

```js
// @ts-nocheck
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'
import Icons from 'unplugin-icons/vite'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vite: {
    plugins: [
      Icons({
        // the feature below is experimental ⬇️
        autoInstall: true
      })
    ]
  }
})
```

I don't know how to fix the types, so I just ignored the check here.

---

Once done, you can go to [icones.js](https://icones.js.org/collection/all?s=xmark) and look for your specific icon, click on it and you'll see this

[image]

Pay attention to the format being `[collection-id]:[name]`, so in your case it's `fa6-solid:xmark`.

Now you can go to any `.vue` file and to convert your `fa6-solid:xmark` format into `~icons/fa6-solid/xmark` while importing it.

```html
<script setup>
import IconXmark from `~icons/fa6-solid/xmark`
</script>

<template>
  <icon-xmark style="font-size: 2em; color: blue" />
</template>
```

Your Nuxt3 project will now be able to auto-install the related package for you.

[image]

And that's all!

---

This `autoInstall` feature works most of the time but is not 100% battle-tested.
I've noticed that it is only able to install 2 icon packs at the same time (a simple restart of the server fixed the issue tho).

If the auto install feature failed, you can always go to npm and look for `@iconify-json/[your collection id]` aka `@iconify-json/fa6-solid` in your case.
NPM is quite good at suggestion the good one from what I've seen.

[image]

---

Here's an example on how to use some other icons

```html
<script setup>
import IconXmark from '~icons/fa6-solid/xmark'
import IconAccountBox from '~icons/mdi/account-box'
import TastyPizza from '~icons/noto-v1/pizza'
import IconPs from '~icons/ri/playstation-line'
</script>

<template>
  <icon-xmark style="font-size: 2em; color: blue" />
  <icon-account-box style="font-size: 2em; color: red" />
  <tasty-pizza style="font-size: 2em" />
  <icon-ps style="font-size: 2em" />
</template>
```

And the actual result, totally customizable with CSS as you can see

[image]

You can check my [github repo](https://github.com/kissu/nuxt3-unplugin-icons) for a fully working example in case it's needed.

PS: an [auto-import feature](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-icons/pull/63) is in the works. Feel free to subscribe to the Github PR for more updates.

PS2: that one could even be used with [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components) if you have a pre-defined array of possible icons so that the bundler can know them in advance thanks to an analytical read.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the rather new package [nuxt-icon](https://github.com/nuxt-modules/icon) which is made by the [CEO of NuxtLabs](https://atinux.com/) and used in the nuxt3/content2 starter template [content-wind](https://github.com/Atinux/content-wind).

**Instalation**

```
npm install --save-dev nuxt-icon

yarn add --dev nuxt-icon
```

**Setting up Nuxt 3**

nuxt.config.ts

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
   modules: ['nuxt-icon']
})
```

**Usage**

Just copy and paste name of icon you want from [icones.js.org](https://icones.js.org). Package will fetch icon and paste to your code. You have 100k+ icons to pick.

```html
<Icon name="logos:google-icon"></Icon>
<Icon name="logos:facebook"></Icon>
<Icon name="logos:apple" fill="#97a3b6"></Icon>
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer with some instructions on how does it work exactly? Usually, a few hyperlinks are not enough for an answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32777019)

Comment: This is how you should write an answer. I edited the answer because it is the best library for icons right now.

Comment: @Mises haha, you could have posted your own answer at this point.

Comment: @kissu No make sense repeating answer. XD I'm not greedy like you. XD

Comment: @Mises if you're adding a substantial amount of explanation that could be deserving it's own answer, I don't feel like it's being greedy. But you do as you'd like for sure.

Comment: @kissu I'm just messing with you

Answer (score 2):

**Only applies when working with custom svg icons**

I usually use [vite-svg-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-svg-loader) when I'm working with custom svg icons (no icon framework). This also works with Nuxt 3.

```
yarn add vite-svg-loader --dev
```

nuxt.config.ts

```
import svgLoader from 'vite-svg-loader'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vite: {
    plugins: [
      svgLoader({})
    ]
  }
})
```

When the setup is done, I create a new component that I can use later in other components (components/IconLoader.vue):

```
<template>
  <component :is="icon" />
</template>

<script>
  const props = defineProps<{ name: string }>()
  const icon = computed(() => 
    defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`../assets/icons/${props.name}.svg`))
  )
</script>
```

Now I can easily show icons with our new custom icon loader component (e.g. App.vue) :

```
<template>
  <icon-loader name="calendar" /> // assuming there is a calendar.svg file in your assets folder.
</template>
```

I usually get my icons from https://heroicons.dev, they work great with Tailwind.