# What is best way to use iconify with Vue3 and Vite?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I can use [@iconify/vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@iconify/vue) to use iconify in a Vue3 project.

Is it the best way or does it still need optimization?

How can I make it into an import with a small size?

Comment: what Optimization do you think could be needed - since you haven't even shown how you are using @iconify/vue (i.e. the documentation for @iconify/vue shows several ways to use it) the answer is a pineapple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by far the best approach right now: https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-icons

Simple, you make the configuration once, you have full customization and flexibility.

Here is a more in depth answer of mine (regarding Nuxt): https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055404/8816585

Comment: I don't like this one too much, because the vscode Iconify intellisense would show icon in the code only on the import... and not for example inline - where <IconClock />

Comment: @DS_web_developer give a try to `>Iconify: Toggle In-place Mode` then.

Comment: maybe you didn't understand... in vs code there is a plugin called Iconify: intellisense... and if I use vue Icon component (@iconify/vue)... I can use it like this <Icon icon="fa:thermometer" />  and vscode would show me the thermometer icon instead of text: fa:thermometer!  But if I would use the unplugin-icons instead, I would see the icon on the import statement: 'import IconThermometer from "~icons/fa/thermometer ";' and not in the markup where I would implement it <IconThermometer />

Comment: @DS_web_developer works perfectly for both on my side.

Comment: could you paste a screen shot for me somewhere?

Comment: @DS_web_developer I guess it would be better that you open a new question actually. Since it's out of the scope of the OP.