# how to render svg icon in nuxt 3

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

I am using nuxt 3 and Compositions API.

I get such a nesting, how to get rid of the extra svg tag?
I would also like to receive svg attributes whenever possible and change, for example, fill

template

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="render"></component>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script

```js
import { h } from "vue";

const { data, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch(svgURL);

const getDataVal = data.value
const SvgToRaw = await getDataVal.text();

const render = () => {
  return h("svg", {
    class: "bar",
    innerHTML: SvgToRaw,
  });
};
```

[Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpUak.png)

I tried to create a virtual DOM tree and get an HTML element from there, not text, but I think this is a bad solution

```js
import hv from "virtual-dom/h";
import diff from "virtual-dom/diff";
import patch from "virtual-dom/patch";
import createElement from "virtual-dom/create-element";

const betaRender = hv("span", { innerHTML: svgString });
var rootNode = createElement(betaRender);
var patches = diff(rootNode);
return patches[0].vNode.innerHTML
```

SSR support is important to me so I can't use standard tools

Comment: Could you please give a read to this one and see if it solves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055404/8816585 ?

Comment: @kissu 
Hello. Your solution is good, but I'd like to abstract away from other libraries as much as possible.
Would like to have my own component.