# How do you get font awesome setup on nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, font-awesome

I am getting the below error hen I try and render this font awesome component in my nuxt 3 app, followed all the npm installs correctly and cannot get the icons in the app without any errors.

```
  at WeakMap.set (<anonymous>)  
  at normalizePropsOptions (./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:3966:11)  
  at createComponentInstance (./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:6957:23)  
  at renderComponentVNode (./node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:171:22)  
  at Module.ssrRenderComponent (./node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:608:12)  
  at _sfc_ssrRender (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:2939:33)  
  at renderComponentSubTree (./node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:253:13)  
  at renderComponentVNode (./node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:188:16)  
  at Module.ssrRenderComponent (./node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:608:12)  
  at _sfc_ssrRender (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:9374:31)
```

This is the line of code that breaks the app

```
<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'user']" />
```

nuxt.config file

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: ["@/assets/css/tailwind.css"],
    build: {
        postcss: {
            postcssOptions: {
                plugins: {
                    tailwindcss: {},
                    autoprefixer: {},
                },
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: ["~/plugins/fontawesome.js"],
    buildModules: [
        ["@pinia/nuxt", { disableVuex: true }],
        ["@nuxtjs/tailwindcss", { config: "@/tailwind.config.js" }],
    ],
    modules: ["@nuxtjs/tailwindcss"],
});
```

plugin file

```
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { fas } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
// import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    // nuxtApp.vueApp.component("FontAwesomeIcon", FontAwesomeIcon);
    library.add(fas);
});
```

I used the plugin because for whatever reason setting up npm @nuxt/fortawesome does not work

package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
        "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.8",
        "@supabase/supabase-js": "^1.35.3",
        "pinia": "^2.0.14"
    }
}
```

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question but I recommend giving this one a try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055404/8816585

Answer (score 3):

This is inconsistent with the latest updates.
Here is how you should install font-awesome on Nuxt3.

1. **Installation**

```bash
npm i -D @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i -D @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i -D @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
npm i -D @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
npm i -D @fortawesome/vue-fontawesome@latest-3    <=== Extremely Critical
```

2. **Nuxt Configuration**

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from '#app'; // remove if 'vue3' is recognised and global by default

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/font-awesome.ts' },
  ],
})
```

3. **Plugin Configuration**

```js
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app'; // remove if 'vue3' is recognised and global by default

import {library, config} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import {
  faHospital as farHospital
} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import {
  faCircleUser as fasCircleUser,
  faBars as fasBars,
  faHospital as fasHospital
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import {faDiscord as fabDiscord} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

// This is important, we are going to let Nuxt not worry about the CSS
config.autoAddCss = false

// You can add your icons directly in this plugin. See other examples for how you
// can add other styles or just individual icons.
library.add(
  farHospital,
  fasHospital,
  fasBars,
  fabDiscord
)

export default defineNuxtPlugin(({vueApp}) => {
  vueApp.component('FontAwesomeIcon', FontAwesomeIcon)
})
```

1. **Test Render**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'hospital']" />
    <font-awesome-icon :icon="['far', 'hospital']" />
    <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'bars']" />
  </div>
<template>
```

Comment: Clearly too much work in 2023.

Comment: hey, great answer. Whats the point of letting nuxt deal with the css? If disabled no css is applied at all to the component. Could you elaborate on that? Thx :)

Comment: ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  defineNuxtPlugin is not defined

Comment: @Wovasteen Gova, ok. Seems like your project doesn't recognise 'vue3' by default. I made the necessary edits.
=> `import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';`

Answer (score 1):

Using my [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055404/8816585), based on [unplugin-icons](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-icons) was able to solve OP's issue.

At the end, something like this is producing the exact same result, but it's universal, performant and you're doing the result only once for any kind of future library.

```html
<script setup>
import IconXmark from `~icons/fa6-solid/xmark`
</script>

<template>
  <icon-xmark style="font-size: 2em; color: blue" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Install packages

```
pnpm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
pnpm i @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
pnpm i @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
pnpm i @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

### Add this plugin

```js
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { faSms } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faFacebook, faTwitter } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

library.add(faTwitter)
library.add(faFacebook)
library.add(faSms)

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
})
```

Enjoy

```html
<template>
  <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-brand fa-whatsapp" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using:

```
npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

In my assets folder i import it:

```
//  /assets/main.css
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
```

Note here: You need the exact path.

Now register it:

```
// nuxt.config.ts

import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt";
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ["~/assets/main.css"],
});
```

And yea, you are good to go. You can go to fontawesome, search for an icon and copy paste it:

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
```

Then you should be able to see it.

Comment: Importing the whole library so? Even if using only 10 icons or so?

Comment: @kissu i agree, not the most elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is due to a recent update but I had to add the name of the icon onto the end of the import statement like this:

```
import { faCartShopping } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faCartShopping'
```

Comment: it is not logic as in the brackets you can add several icons...