# Vue + NuxtJS Web Preview gives "Unexpected token '<'" when importing a package

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

I can't figure out why I am getting this error, but for some reason I am getting this error whenever I try to simply use a package I imported. I was simply working on my page and the package was working normally until it suddenly gave me this error. I figured out that it was the package that was causing this error, but I have no idea how it suddenly broke or how to fix it. Thank you

```
<template>
     <icons name="angle-down"></icons>
</template>
<script>
     import icons from "v-svg-icons";

     export default {
          components: {
               icons
          }
     }
</script>
```

here is the package that I am using:

https://vuejsexamples.com/svg-icons-for-vuejs/

Comment: According to the usage page, you should register the component with `Vue.component("icon", icons)` and use the name in `""` as your html tag name. Have you done so?

Comment: Or simply use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055404/8816585