# Children of NuxtLink rendered twice (hydration error?)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, mismatch, hydration

[image: span rendered twice]

My hunch is that there is some hydration mismatch where the `FontAwesomeIcon` was not rendered on the server (only the `span`) and then on the client both child nodes of the `NuxtLink` were rendered (the `svg` and the `span`), prompting Nuxt to render the `span` twice.

The console does not return an error, though.

Any thoughts on how to debug this?

This is the Vue component:

```vue
<template>
  <ul v-if="routes.length > 0" class="col-span-2 flex flex-col">
    <li v-for="(item, i) in routes" :key="item.name">
      <NuxtLink :to="item.path" target="_blank">
        <FontAwesomeIcon :icon="item.icon" class="mr-3" fixed-width />
        <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
      </NuxtLink>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    links: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => ["instagram", "facebook", "email"],
    },
  },
  computed: {
    routes() {
      return [
        {
          name: "instagram",
          path: "https://www.instagram.com/insta.name/",
          title: "Instagram",
          icon: ["fab", "instagram"],
        },
        {
          name: "facebook",
          path: "https://www.facebook.com/fb.name",
          title: "Facebook",
          icon: ["fab", "facebook"],
        },
        {
          name: "email",
          path: "mailto:hello@example.com",
          title: "Email",
          icon: ["fas", "envelope"],
        },
      ].filter((e) => this.links.includes(e.name));
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure but apparently the error is only display when you build your project for production, try that one out. Otherwise, double check that your thing is actually as expected on the server side by disabling JS. And be careful with async code.

Comment: Yes, it's only in production and only with the `<FontAwesomeIcon />` component. This component is not async afaik. Wrapping the children in a `<ClientOnly>` component tackled the double hydration but it is not a solution because it's beside the point of SSR...

Comment: Try to compare both the DOM of the element on the server vs on the client. `client-only` is indeed not the best solution but at the same time, if it's an icon it doesn't really matter SEO-wise or anything. Maybe try to look into their specific github issues to see if they have something related, otherwise I can also recommend this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055404/8816585 Works great!

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solve it?

Comment: @AlexanderHorner feel free to post a new question to get your issue solved.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution? I have the same issue without errors.

Comment: I did not yet find a solution other than wrapping the `<FontAwesomeIcon />` in a `<ClientOnly />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanes solution I have come across is this: transpile the `@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome` package in your `nuxt.config.ts`:

```js
// nuxt.config.ts

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  build: {
    transpile: [
      '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome',
    ]
  },
  // ...
})
```

The solution was posted here:
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/16014#discussioncomment-2477885.

I found that it's enough to transpile `@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome`.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a better solution, see my other answer.**

Wrap you `<FontAwesomeIcon />` in a `<span>` like so:

```
...
<NuxtLink to="/path" target="_blank">
  <span><FontAwesomeIcon :icon="icon" fixed-width /></span>
  <span>{{ title }}</span>
</NuxtLink>
...
```

All credit goes to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73487636/4862595