# Why does <font-awesome-icon /> output whatever follows twice when using Nuxt v3 static generation?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, font-awesome, nuxtjs3

I am using [vue-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome) with Nuxt 3 as described [here](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/vue/use-with) and I'm seeing this weird behaviour. Say I have something like this

```
<a href="https://example.com"><font-awesome-icon icon="fa-brands fa-twitter" />Example</a>
```

if I run the dev server, everything is fine, but if I run `generate` and serve the output through a static HTTP server, I get "Example" printed twice. If I wrap the text in a tag, I get the tag and text twice (i.e. `<span>Example</span><span>Example</span>`). Weirdly enough, though, the generated HTML does not contain the repetition, so I suspect something weird is going on in the browser.

You can grab the generated site from here as a reproducible test case. https://andreafranceschini.org/files/afnuxt.tgz

I hear `vue-fontawesome` isn't super happy with SSR and static generation, but I also see others using it just fine in the same way so I wonder what I may be doing wrong?

**EDIT** I also posted this as a "bug" [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome/issues/384).

**EDIT 2** A workaround is to enclose the icon alone in something else, like a `span` tag.

Comment: I… dont? There are two tags, one is `a`, the other is `font-awesome-icon`.

Comment: Have you tried closing the tag `<font-awesome-icon icon="fa-brands fa-twitter"></font-awesome-icon>`?

Comment: @IgorMoraru No difference from the self-closing tag ` />`.

Comment: experienced this, thanks for detailing the workaround!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a workaround, which is to enclose the icon alone in something else, like a `span` tag.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following to your `nuxt.config.ts` file:

```js
build: {
  transpile: [
    '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core',
    '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons',
    '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons',
    '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons',
    '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
  ]
}
```

(Adjust the specific icon package imports as required.)

I can only find this solution mentioned online in two places [[1]](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/3823#discussioncomment-2546975) [[2]](https://caleb-smith.dev/blog/adding-font-awesome-to-nuxt-3), neither of which mention this duplication issue. It is also notably absent from all official documentation.

That said, for me at least, this fixes both this issue and the issue of `Could not find one or more icon(s)` error messages in the console.