# How can I include Fontawesome 6 in Nuxt 3 project?

Tags: vuejs3, font-awesome, nuxtjs3

first of all my configuration:

nuxt.config.ts

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    // if you want to use static HTML generation (SSG)
    target: 'static',

    // if you want to use server-side rendering (SSR)
    ssr: true,

    css: [
        'assets/scss/main.css',
        'assets/scss/header.css',
        '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'
    ],

    build: {
        transpile: [
            '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome',
            '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core',
            '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons',
            '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons',
            '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
        ]
    }

})
```

/plugins/fontawesome.js

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';

/** Fontawesome for Nuxt 3
 * https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/vue/use-with#nuxt 
 * 
*/

// import the fontawesome core
import { library, config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

// import font awesome icon component 
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

// import specific icons 
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

// This is important, we are going to let Nuxt worry about the CSS
config.autoAddCss = false


export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  console.log('[Plugin]', 'Font Awesome')
  
  // You can add your icons directly in this plugin. See other examples for how you
  // can add other styles or just individual icons.
  library.add(fas);

  nuxtApp.vueApp.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
})
```

```
<template>
  <header class="header">
    <Logo />

    coffee <font-awesome-icon icon="fas coffee" /> 
    flag <font-awesome-icon icon="fas fa-flag" />
    search <font-awesome-icon icon="fas fa-magnifying-glass" />
    search 2 <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass" />

    <nav>
      <nuxt-link :to="{ path: '/' }">
        Home
      </nuxt-link>
      <nuxt-link :to="{ path: '/getting-started' }">
        Getting Started
      </nuxt-link>
      <nuxt-link :to="{ path: '/faq' }">
        FAQ
      </nuxt-link>
      <nuxt-link :to="{ path: '/search' }">
        <font-awesome-icon icon="fas fa-magnifying-glass" />
      </nuxt-link>
    </nav>

  </header>
</template>
```

**Problem**
When I start npx nuxi dev and look at the page via localhost, the icons appear for 1 second and then are no longer visible. I have been searching for a solution for quite some time because I could not find an error right away.

**Warning - console**

```
[Vue warn]: Hydration node mismatch:
- Client vnode: font-awesome-icon 
- Server rendered DOM: <svg class=​"svg-inline--fa fa-magnifying-glass" style aria-hidden=​"true" focusable=​"false" data-prefix=​"fas" data-icon=​"magnifying-glass" role=​"img" xmlns=​"http:​/​/​www.w3.org/​2000/​svg" viewBox=​"0 0 512 512">​…​</svg>​  
  at <Navigation> 
  at <Default > 
  at <AsyncComponentWrapper > 
  at <BaseTransition mode="out-in" appear=false persisted=false  ... > 
  at <Transition name="layout" mode="out-in" > 
  at <Anonymous> 
  at <App key=1 > 
  at <NuxtRoot>
```

Comment: I still recommend this one as of today: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055404/8816585

Answer (score 8):

You can wrap the component in a `<client-only>`, so it only renders client-side.

```
<client-only>
 <font-awesome-icon icon="fas fa-flag" />
</client-only>
```

Comment: works fine, but is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add `'@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'` to your transpiler. You're using the free package, but transpile only the pro.