# How to import Oh Vue Icons inside Nuxt 3?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

Normally in Vue I have main.ts file so I can just import and mount Vue icon into the app, for example:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { OhVueIcon, addIcons } from 'oh-vue-icons'
import { MdDragindicator, HiTrash, HiPlus, HiSolidSearch, BiTextLeft, BiTypeH1, BiTypeH2, BiTypeH3, BiHr, BiQuote } from 'oh-vue-icons/icons'

import '@/assets/css/main.css'
import App from './App.vue'

addIcons(MdDragindicator, HiTrash, HiPlus, HiSolidSearch, BiTextLeft, BiTypeH1, BiTypeH2, BiTypeH3, BiHr, BiQuote)

const app = createApp(App)
app.component('v-icon', OhVueIcon)
app.mount('#app')
```

So how can I do the same thing in Nuxt 3 where I only have `nuxt.config.ts`

Comment: Tried that one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055404/8816585

Answer (score 0):

You have to install and configure a plugin for that called vite-svg-loader.

In your Nuxt config file, doing something like

```
import svgLoader from 'vite-svg-loader'

(...)

vite: {
    css: {
      (...)
    },
    plugins: [svgLoader()],
  },

(...)
```

npm package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-svg-loader

Comment: This does not directly answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. install

```
yarn add oh-vue-icons
```

2. plugins folder create a file just likes "oh-vue-icons.js"

> `~/plugins/oh-vue-icons.js`

```
import { OhVueIcon, addIcons } from "oh-vue-icons";
import { FaFlag } from "oh-vue-icons/icons";

addIcons(FaFlag);

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.component("v-icon", OhVueIcon);
});
```

3. add to nuxt.config.ts

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({

  plugins: ["~/plugins/oh-vue-icons.js"],

  <!-- it's optional start-->
  build: {
    transpile: ["oh-vue-icons"]
  },
  vite: {
    optimizeDeps: {
      exclude: ["oh-vue-icons/icons"]
    },
    ssr: {
      noExternal: ["oh-vue-icons"]
    }
  }
  <!-- it's optional end -->

})
```

4. use it

```
<template>
  <v-icon name="fa-flag"/>
</template>
```