# Import statements breaks script setup Nuxtjs 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

It seems that when I'm using the `import` statement in the `<script setup>` all code below it stops working.

I installed the [@heroicons](https://heroicons.com) package and use the import statement to use it as a component in my `<template>`. But everything below the import statements does not work anymore. My code:

```html
<template>
  <HomeIcon class="w-5 h-5">
  <h1>{{myName}}</h1>
</template>

<script setup>
import {HomeIcon} from '@heroicons/vue/24/outline'

const myName = ref('username')
</script>
```

When running the code above I do **not** see "username" as a heading as specified in my code. I also see a ESlint warning

> myName is declared but it's value is never read

The moment I comment the `import` statement, the `myName` ref seems to work again.

What I use:

- VS Code
- Nuxtjs 3
- Tailwind CSS
- Heroicons package
- PNPM as package manager

Comment: I'd give a try to that one, maybe it'll fix the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055404/8816585

Comment: Also, maybe try with `import HomeIcon from '@heroicons/vue/24/outline'`? Not sure, never saw that kind of issue before.

Comment: I'll try using the method linked above.

Comment: Tell me if you have more issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the various issues, I'll take the reference of your code here for the changelog:

- `<HomeIcon>` wasn't closed aka `<HomeIcon />`
- `vue` was missing as a dependency for `@heroicons`
- PNPM needed to be [shamefully hoist to work properly](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/7385#issuecomment-1243505529)
- clean reinstall of your `node_modules` + `pnpm-lock.yaml`

Here is the Pull request with the various fixes: https://github.com/flackokj/nuxt-issues/pull/1/files

Answer (score 1):

What seems to work is by extracting the `import` statement in a different `<script>` and also exporting it as a component.
I now have 2 `<script>` tags; one with 'setup' attribute and one without.

My final code:

```
<template>
    <HomeIcon class="w-5 h-5" />
    <h1>{{ myName }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
import { HomeIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/24/outline';

export default {
    components: {
        HomeIcon,
    },
};
</script>

<script setup>
const myName = ref('username');
</script>
```

But even though everything looks to be working fine in the `<script setup>`, it seems that my linter plugin still doesn't recognize that I **do** use the declared variable (see img1).
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrzxG.png)

List of plugins I use:

- ESLint
- Javascript (ES6) code snippets
- Prettier
- Vetur
- Vue Language Features (Volar)

Comment: You should clearly not have to do such thing. Can you try to replicate your issue with a brand new project that could be hosted on Github?

Comment: You can follow [this repo](https://github.com/flackokj/nuxt-issues/tree/issue-1) where I added some test code which reproduces the bug for me. Thanks for helping!