# not displayed v-icon with active middleware nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I can’t solve the problem, the v-icon are displayed normally if the middleware is not enabled, maybe my middleware is not correct?

template:

```
<v-icon>{{'mdi-close'}}</v-icon>
```

script:

```
middleware: ['auth'],
```

middleware/auth.js

```
export default function({store, redirect}){
    if (!store.getters.hasToken) {
        redirect('/login')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing related to the middleware here, the icon just looks wrong.
Looking at [this example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons/#color), you need to have the following

```html
<v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with nuxt, but it is OK in plain Vuetify to use author's syntax... Imagine that you need to dynamically switch icons by some condition - you should use variable that will contain some string with icon's name. Is it impossible to do it in nuxt?

Comment: @AlexanderShkirkov does that one work? If it does, you can always use a slot yeah. Or even use your own icons: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055404/8816585 (works with Nuxt2 too)

Comment: the example is correct, here is a more complicated one `<v-icon v-if="!item.file">
            {{ open ? 'mdi-folder-open' : 'mdi-folder' }}
          </v-icon>`

Comment: @IgorPanenko the example doesn't work I guess? What do you see in the DOM as a difference? Then, you would need to use slots: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#slots Or my approach regarding icons (better alternative IMO).

Comment: there are no changes to the DOM, and this example does not work https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/#append-and-label

Comment: Then, your Vuetify configuration maybe have some issues.

Comment: I tried it on a pure example, there is no such problem, but on the current project I wanted to add an icon in the admin panel, and the middleware does not work, tell me how to catch the conflict

Comment: You're using Nuxt Auth module? Not sure how to debug the icon, would need more details form your side here.

Comment: I myself am in doubt, I remove the middleware, everything works, there are no modules, everything is on cookies and database

Comment: found a difference, no ```.mdi-close::before {
    content: "\F0156";
}```

Comment: What is the middleware about so?

Answer (score 0):

decided

```
npm install @mdi/font
```

nuxt.config.js

```
css: ['@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css']
```