# Nuxt 3 / Vuetify 3 - How to import Material Icons?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vuetifyjs3

I am trying to setup Material Design Icons, and I have the following config:

nuxt.config.ts

````
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt';
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'],
    css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass', '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'],
    build: {
        transpile: ['vuetify'],
    },
    vite: {
        define: {
            'process.env.DEBUG': false,
        },
    },
})`
```
````

But in terminal I am keep getting the same message whatever I try

[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/materialdesignicons.min.css.map"

I installed @mdi/font package and followed the vuetify3 official docs but no success.

Also, I have installed Nuxt 3 and Vuetify 3, and dev dependencies sass-loader and sass.

Icons are shown, no problems with display in <v-icon> tag but in terminal I keep getting the same error message.

I have been Googling a lot but I can't seem to find the answer.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What for you need Tailwind CSS and vuetify ?

Comment: If you want to use Tailwind CSS and need full UI library use Tailwind UI or Daisy UI they are based on Tailwind CSS. And for Icons `nuxt-icon` library. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72052807/how-to-use-any-icons-with-nuxt3/73810640#73810640

Comment: Give a try to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055404/8816585

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell vuetify to use the material icons as icon pack in your plugins/vuetify.ts.
To do so you have to install the mdi font, as you already did, and then set it in the vuetify icons Object in your defineNuxtPlugin.

When done, it should look like this:

```js
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import {aliases, mdi} from "vuetify/lib/iconsets/mdi";
// make sure to also import the coresponding css
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
 // Ensure your project is capable of handling css files
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    const vuetify = createVuetify({ // Replaces new Vuetify(...)
        theme: {
            defaultTheme: 'dark'
        },
        icons: {
            defaultSet: 'mdi',
            aliases,
            sets: {
                mdi
            }
        },
    })

    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

You can then simply use it like this:

```
<v-icon icon="mdi-minus" />
```

For a more detailed explanation, visit [This Article](https://www.the-koi.com/projects/how-to-set-up-a-project-with-nuxt3-and-vuetify3-with-a-quick-overview/)

Answer (score 1):

I just import materialdesignicons to  plugins/vuetify.ts. It works for me.

- first install "@mdi/font" and then use this config:

  ```
   // plugins/vuetify.ts
   import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
   import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css";
   export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
   const vuetify = createVuetify({
           ssr: true,
           theme: {
               defaultTheme: "light",
           },
       });
       nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify);
   });
  ```