# Github error 404 on console with payload js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, http-status-code-404, github-pages

[image]

I have just deployed my Nuxt app and there are some errors with payload js, I have no idea what error is this.

---

Here is my file directory

[image: dfile directory looks like this:]

---

I found that `payload.js file` which is in error: `...1673214939/<page-name>/payload.js`

and there is in all `payload.js` files same code:

```js
__NUXT_JSONP__("/albums", {data:[{}],fetch:{},mutations:[]});
```

It is working well on localhost but in github, icons in Navbar are not apearing because of errors.

There my nuxt.config.js and package.json files:

`nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {

  head: {
    title: 'Florida',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en',
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },

  target: 'static',
  router: {
    base: '/FloridaGifts/'
  },

  css: ["./assets/main.scss"],

  plugins: [
    {
      src: './plugins/vue-icons.js',
      mode: 'client'
    },
  ],

  components: true,

  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
  ],

  modules: [
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    [
      '@nuxtjs/firebase',

      {
        config: {
          apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
          authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
          databaseURL: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
          projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
          storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
          messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
          appId: process.env.APP_ID,
          measurementId: process.env.MEASURMENT_ID
        },

        services: {
          auth: {
            initialize: {
              onAuthStateChangedAction: 'onAuthStateChangedAction',
            }
          },
          database: true,
          storage: true
        }
      }
    ]
  ],

  axios: {
    baseURL: '/',
  },

  build: {},
}
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "deploy": "push-dir --dir=dist --branch=gh-pages --cleanup",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:prettier": "prettier --check .",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js && npm run lint:prettier",
    "lintfix": "prettier --write --list-different . && npm run lint:js -- --fix",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/firebase": "^8.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.22.0",
    "core-js": "^3.25.3",
    "hooper": "^0.3.4",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "vue": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^11.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.1.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.5.1",
    "jest": "^29.1.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.1.2",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "push-dir": "^0.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.4.1",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4",
    "webpack": "^4.45.0"
  }
}
```

And when I was deploying it, I have run these commands

`npm run generate`
`npm install push-dir --save-dev`

`npm run generate npm run deploy`

link to repository: [repository](https://github.com/Ravshanovich99/FloridaGifts)

link to gh-pages(deploy): [deploy](https://ravshanovich99.github.io/FloridaGifts/)

Warnings in dev:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Source of DOM missmatch error:

```js
else if (hasConsole_1 && !config.silent) {
  console.error("[Vue warn]: ".concat(msg).concat(trace));
}
```

Comment: What does your file directory look like

Comment: @Kyrony added file directory photo

Comment: Hey, first off forget Github pages. It's not worth the effort, to host your app on either Netlify or Vercel. Also, it looks like your app is not running an actual server. Please share some context regarding your app (Nuxt configuration, `package.json`). Also, please add the commands you're running when deploying it to production + try those locally first.

Comment: @kissu Thank you for your help! Edited question below your comment

Comment: You can remove `@nuxtjs/dotenv` module, it's baked-in already. Otherwise, a Nuxt2 SSG app will be super easy to host on Netlify/Vercel, give it a try. The Nuxt config looks fine.

Comment: @kissu I added repository link and link of deploy could you check it please? Everything is ok, but icons in navbar and icons in footer are not appearing. I could not understand why(

Comment: Do tou have any warnings while dev and running the generated app locally?

Comment: Yes, I have. With duplicated id

Comment: Mind sharing those? Not in front of a computer right now.

Comment: Sure, I added images of warnings

Comment: The warnings could be forgotten. The errors meanwhile are important to fix. The one about unique keys is pretty self-explanatory, you have the same key at several places. Use your Vue devtools to inspect where the duplicate may come from. Should be pretty quick to find out. As for the DOM mismatch, here we are: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978474/8816585

Comment: @kissu I fixed errors with duplicated keys, but for DOM missmatch couldn't. I tried all methods in your link below, changed all toggles to v-show, changed all block elements to inline elements inside <a> and <p>. And I have read Lichter's aricle and opened source of DOM missmatch warning and there is (I added this code to question there it is looking mess) I commented all consoles but cant figure out why still this error

Comment: `FloridaGifts` + `like-counter` is the place to look for. The source you've edited is the actual code in the source code of Nuxt, not helpful in our case. Focus on the 2 warnings lines as I just wrote. Disable the JS and inspect the difference between both JS and static markup to find out the difference. Be careful for the next time too, those errors are easier to fix when debugged early as you can see.

Comment: It was because of bootstrap icons in warning as you said `mismatching childnodes vs. vnodes` I wrapped them into `<ClientOnly>` and it finally worked thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP solved the issue with a `client-only` as proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978474/8816585

Fixing some unique ID keys while using `v-for` also helped.

I also recommend [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055404/8816585) to have a universal way of using icons without all the pain or setting it up and dealing with various quirks.